# For Next Loop to calculate running total won't work

Tags: vba, list, for-loop, listbox, cumulative-sum

The majority of my code works other than the 'Calculate Totals' button. I have three listboxes and need my 'Calculate Totals' button to iterate through the selected costs in the 'lstCosts' listbox. However in Option Strict On I receive an error as "List is not a member of Double" and "ListCount is not a member of Double" Can someone help rectify this? I know my code is close to working I just don't know how.

Below is my code which isn't working:

```
Private Sub btnAddCourse_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddCourse.Click

    'Declare variables
    Dim strCourse As String 'To hold the Course Values
    Dim strLocation As String 'To hold the Location values

    'Item Indexing
    'Identifies the four Course strings
    strCourse = lstCourse.Items(0).ToString()
    strCourse = lstCourse.Items(1).ToString()
    strCourse = lstCourse.Items(2).ToString()
    strCourse = lstCourse.Items(3).ToString()

    'Identifies the four Location strings
    strLocation = lstLocation.Items(0).ToString()
    strLocation = lstLocation.Items(1).ToString()
    strLocation = lstLocation.Items(2).ToString()
    strLocation = lstLocation.Items(3).ToString()


    If lstCourse.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        'Error Message for no course selected
        MessageBox.Show("Select a course.", "Error", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    ElseIf lstLocation.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        'Error message for no location selected
        MessageBox.Show("Select a location.", "Error", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        'Essential Linux and Belfast selected = £705
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 0 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(705)
        'Essential Linux and Coleraine selected = £600
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 0 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(600)
        'Essential Linux and Jordasntown selected = £600
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 0 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(600)
        'Essential Linux and Magee selected = £630
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 0 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(630)
        'Project Management and Belfast selected £520
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 1 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(520)
        'Project Management and Coleraine selected = £450
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 1 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(450)
        'Project Management and Jordanstown selected = £450
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 1 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(450)
        'Project Management and Magee selected = £470
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 1 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(470)
        'Overview of net and Belfast selected = £705
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 2 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(705)
        'Overview of net and Coleraine selected = £575
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 2 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(575)
        'Overview of net and Jordanstown selected = £575
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 2 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(575)
        'Overview of net and Magee selected = £605
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 2 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(605)
        'PHP and Belfast selected = £780
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 3 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(780)
        'PHP and Coleraine selected = £675
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 3 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(675)
        'PHP and Jordanstown selected = £675
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 3 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(675)
        'PHP and Magee selected = £705
    ElseIf lstCourse.SelectedIndex = 3 And lstLocation.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        lstCosts.Items.Add(705)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculateTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculateTotal.Click

    Dim lstCosts As Double
    Dim lblTotalCost As Double

    For lstCosts = 0 To lstCosts.ListCount - 1
        lblTotalCost = lblTotalCost + CDbl(lstCosts.List(lstCosts))
    Next lstCosts

    lblTotalCost = lstCosts

End Sub

Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click

    'Clears the fields
    lstCourse.ClearSelected()
    lstLocation.ClearSelected()
    lstCosts.Items.Clear()
    lblTotalCost.Text = String.Empty

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

    'Closes the Program
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

when I Looked before there was more code to support my solution.
I think you have 2 issues local vs global naming, and assignment.

```
Private Sub btnCalculateTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculateTotal.Click

'Declare variables
Dim lvIterate As Double '
Dim lvTotalOfCost As Double

'Calculate Total Cost
For lvIterate = 0 To lstCosts.ListCount - 1

    lvTotalOfCost = lvTotalOfCost + CDbl(lstCosts.List(lvIterate))
Next

lblTotalCost.Text = lvTotalOfCost
```

End Sub

Hope it solves you issue.

Comment: That still doesn't seem to work, it still has the exact same issue, with 'ListCount' and '.list' not being members of Double

Comment: what type of control is lstCosts?  listBox and listView in vb use "lstCosts.Items.Count"

Comment: "lstCosts.Items.Count" also doesn't seem to work I'm quite confused. lstCosts is the name of my listbox which holds the Costs. After iterating through each cost in the listbox, the Total Costs label "lblTotalCost" should display the sum of all of these costs

Comment: I mocked up the page, add the subs.  I did some digging and this is what I got

    Private Sub btnCalculateTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculateTotal.Click

        Dim lvTotalCost As Double
        Dim x As Integer

        For Each lvitem As ListViewItem In Me.lstCosts.Items
            x = CDbl(lvitem.Text)
            lvTotalCost += x
        Next

        lblTotalCost.Text = lvTotalCost

    End Sub
    
    see how it works in you app
    remember to comment the original
    I will hold on to the project for a few days

Comment: Private Sub btnCalculateTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculateTotal.Click

        Dim lvTotalCost As Double
        Dim x As Integer

        For Each lvitem As ListViewItem In Me.lstCosts.Items
            x = CInt(CDbl(lvitem.Text))
            lvTotalCost += x
        Next lvitem = lvTotalCost

    End Sub

Comment: So that is what I placed into my program and for "= lvTotalCost" I received the error "End of Statement expected" and I was corrected to place CInt in front of "(CDbl(lvitem.Text))" and it won't start now

Comment: It is working in my project'    Private Sub btnCalculateTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculateTotal.Click

        Dim lvTotalCost As Double
        Dim x As Integer

        For Each lvitem As ListViewItem In Me.lstCosts.Items
            x = CDbl(lvitem.Text)
            lvTotalCost += x
        Next

        lblTotalCost.Text = lvTotalCost

    End Sub'